# How to make a gallery?

Tags: android, android-studio, aviary, adobecreativesdk

Hello :) I took months with the problem, I already read the documentation.

https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/gettingstarted/index.html

[My application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tODl7.png)

The image is connected to a url :/

I want to know how to do to put a gallery and the user can select the image so you can edit, and the same with the camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Launching the Gallery

If you want to choose an image from the device's Gallery, you can do something like this:

```
Intent galleryPickerIntent = new Intent();
galleryPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
galleryPickerIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryPickerIntent, "Select an Image"), 203); // Can be any int
```

This starts a new activity that we expect to give us some kind of result (in this case, it will be an image `Uri`).

A common use case is to launch the Gallery when the user clicks a button:

```
View.OnClickListener openGalleryButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent galleryPickerIntent = new Intent();
        galleryPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        galleryPickerIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryPickerIntent, "Select an Image"), 203); // Can be any int
    }
};
mOpenGalleryButton.setOnClickListener(openGalleryButtonListener);
```

This code will either open the Gallery directly, or first show the user a chooser that lets them select which app to use as a source of images.

## Receiving results

To receive the image that the user selects, we will use the `onActivityResult()` method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mAuthSessionHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 203) { // the int we used for startActivityForResult()

        // You can do anything here. This is just an example.
        mSelectedImageUri = data.getData();
        mSelectedImageView.setImageURI(mSelectedImageUri);

    }
}
```

I put some example code in the `if` block, but what you do there will depend on your app.

Answer (score 3):

You can learn it from google gallery, here is the source code https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/

Comment: Where do I put it? :/

Comment: This is a complete project, you have to read the code first, see which part is good for your project, then just copy that part and do some changes into your project.